# Possible to run Blade on variable?

Tags: laravel-4

Is it possible to run the Blade engine on an variable?

Let's say i have variable called "`$render`" which equals to "`@if($something == $something) $(".hello").show(); @endif`"

And i would then run something like "`View::make($render);`".

I am trying to add this functionality to a package that Minifies JS files.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) and from my experience, you can't.

I think what you are looking for is `@include('some_file')`. Whic means you will ALWAYS run the @if statement.